# UIButton fail to be clicked on the calloutView of the Annotation

Tags: ios, annotations, uibutton, mkmapview, uiresponder

[image: Button on the calloutView]

[image: the structure of my calloutView]

The problem I encountered: I click on the button, but it seems that the CalloutView received my clicking instead of the UIButton.

Some explanation first: 1.the "SYSUMyAnnoCalloutView" is a MKPinAnnotationView  2.the "SYSUMyCalloutImageView" is a UIImageView, which I init it and addSubview on the "SYSUMyAnnoCalloutView"  3. the UIButton and the UILabel was addSubviewed in the "SYSUMyCalloutImageView"

Corresponding code:
1. In the "SYSUMyAnnoCalloutView.m"

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
if (selected){
    [self.calloutImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(-75, -100, 230, 130)];

    [self animateCalloutAppearance];
    //[self.calloutImageView becomeFirstResponder];
    //[self.calloutImageView.detailButton addTarget:self.calloutImageView action:@selector(clickForDetail) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:self.calloutImageView];
    [self setCanShowCallout:NO];
}
else
{
    //Remove your custom view...
    [self.calloutImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```

2. In the "SYSUMyCalloutImageView.m"

   ```
   - (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
   {
   self = [super initWithImage:image];
   if (self){
       //Label
   CGRect boundsForLabel;
   boundsForLabel.origin.x = 20;
   boundsForLabel.origin.y = 50;
   boundsForLabel.size.width = self.bounds.size.width - 100;
   boundsForLabel.size.height = 20;
   self.messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:boundsForLabel];
   self.messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [self addSubview:self.messageLabel];
   //detailButton
   CGRect buttonRect;
   buttonRect.origin.x = 20;
   buttonRect.origin.y = 80;
   buttonRect.size.width = boundsForLabel.size.width-50;
   buttonRect.size.height = 30;
   self.detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   [self.detailButton setFrame:buttonRect];
   [self.detailButton setTitle:@"Click for detail" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   self.detailButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   //[self.detailButton addTarget:self.superview action:@selector(clickForDetail) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self addSubview:self.detailButton];
   ```

   }
   return self;
   }

could anybody solve my problem?? will be really appreciate that:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default an UIImageView do not accept user interactions.

You should try adding this line of code in the `initWithImage` of your SYSUMyCalloutImageView.m

```
[self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```